# Is it possible to reference jre system library in Android project?

Tags: android, awt, java

I developed my java code using awt classes. When I copied this code to my Android project I was getting errors. So I added JRE system library to the build path. Will it work now?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Android UI isn't built on AWT. (A few AWT classes are available, but not many - fonts, basically.) You should only use the libraries listed in the [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: But when I referenced jre system library to my code, all the errors showing that java.awt is not found went away.

Comment: @user1851671: Sure, but that's not the same as it actually *working* afterwards, is it? I'm not sure why you asked the question here instead of actually trying it...

Answer (score 1):

No when you move it to an Android platform.

Android is a language that uses the Java syntax/keywords but implements a different API. As long as they could the kept it and copied it (see the more common classes like `java.lang.String`), but sometimes they could not

If the class is missing in Android emulator it will be missing in the device, and more likely that not you will not be able to port it.

Comment: Regarding porting: someone tried and gave up http://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/